# Cordova Plugins Installation MAC

Tags: android, ios, macos, cordova

I am using Cordova 3.3.0 and I want to install the camera and network plugins. In netbeans it is very simple to do so but I can't understand how this can be accomplished on MAC. Please note that I am very new to this.

I am trying to run the following command in the terminal:

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-camera.git
```

An error is saying

```
-bash: cordova: command not found
```

Can anyone guide me what needs to be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Cordova is well installed on your Mac, you need to add "/usr/local/share/npm/bin" directory to your $PATH variable. Open your Terminal / Command line and type:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/share/npm/bin
```

Else, before install Cordova typing :

```
npm install -g cordova
```